# C# Generic XML reader code

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I have a program, which parses three different CrystalReport XML files (similar structure, but different descendants levels) and then populates values into a class.

Here is example of first one:

```
    public static List<VyplatnePasky> DeserialzieRozuctovanieMzdy(ref List<VyplatnePasky> _pasky, string sPath)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(sPath);
        var formattedAreaPairReport = from d in document.Descendants("FormattedReport".AddNamespace())
                                                        .Descendants("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace())
                                                        .Descendants("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace())
                                      select d.Element("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace());

        if (formattedAreaPairReport.Count() == 0)
        {
            //empty;
            InsertErrorMessage("<formattedAreaPairReport> contains no data! No Data to parse from.", "DeserialzieRozuctovanieMzdy");
            return _pasky;
        }

        //check if any sequence contains any matching elements
        var GotElements = formattedAreaPairReport.Elements("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace()).Where(n=>n.Attribute("Level").Value == "3" && n.Attribute("Type").Value == "Group");
        if (GotElements == null)
        {
            InsertErrorMessage("There are no matching elements under <formattedAreaPairReport>.", "DeserialzieRozuctovanieMzdy");
            return _pasky;
        }

        foreach (XElement xElement in GotElements)
        {
            RozuctovanieMzda_Values(xElement, ref _pasky);
        }

        return _pasky;
    }
```

and here is the second one (second XML document parser):

```
    public static List<VyplatnePasky> DeserializeVyplatnePasky(string sPath)
    {
        List<VyplatnePasky> _pasky = new List<VyplatnePasky>();

        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(sPath);
        var formattedAreaPairReport = from d in document.Descendants("FormattedReport".AddNamespace())
                                      select d.Element("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace());

        if (formattedAreaPairReport.Count() == 0)
        {
            //empty;
            InsertErrorMessage("<formattedAreaPairReport> contains no data! No Data to parse from.", "DeserializeVyplatnePasky");
        }
        else
        {
            //sequence contains data
            foreach (XElement xElement in formattedAreaPairReport.Elements("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace()))
            {
                VyplatnePasky _paska = new VyplatnePasky();
                VyplatnePasky_Items(xElement, ref _paska);

                _pasky.Add(_paska);
            }
        }
        return _pasky;
    }
```

As you can see from the code above, all three XML parsing methods look almost the same; the main difference is how deep I go in the descendants under e.g. **formattedAreaPairReport**

What I would like to do, is to make this code more professional and reusable by creating Generic void that can be used by all three methods.

I was thinking of creating multiple Delegates, where I would pass my lambda commands such as:

```
            var formattedAreaPairReport = ProcessFirstLevel(from d in document.Descendants("FormattedReport".AddNamespace())
                                      select d.Element("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace()));
```

however it would become just one big messy void.

The question is - is this actually doable/worth doing? Could you help, please?

Comment: These methods look quite different to make them generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) the code up a bit by using some [clean coding](http://www.bitnative.com/presentations/clean-code-writing-code-for-humans/) techniques.  Try doing something like this:

```
public static List<VyplatnePasky> DeserialzieRozuctovanieMzdy(ref List<VyplatnePasky> _pasky, string sPath)
{
    var formattedAreaPairReport =
    tryToGetItemsFromDocument
    (
        sPath,
        document=>from d in document.Descendants("FormattedReport".AddNamespace())
                  .Descendants("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace())
                  .Descendants("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace())
                  select d.Element("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace()),
        "DeserialzieRozuctovanieMzdy"
    );

    addItemsToVyplatnePasky(formattedAreaPairReport, ref _pasky);
    return _pasky;
}

public static List<VyplatnePasky> DeserializeVyplatnePasky(string sPath)
{
    List<VyplatnePasky> _pasky = new List<VyplatnePasky>();

    var formattedAreaPairReport =
    tryToGetItemsFromDocument
    (
        sPath,
        document=>from d in document.Descendants("FormattedReport".AddNamespace())
                  select d.Element("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace()),
        "DeserializeVyplatnePasky"
    );
    addItemsToVyplatnePasky2(formattedAreaPairReport, _pasky);
    return _pasky;
}

private static void addItemsToVyplatnePasky(IEnumerable<XElement> formattedAreaPairReport, ref List<VyplatnePasky> _pasky)
{
    if (formattedAreaPairReport.Count() > 0)
    {
        //check if any sequence contains any matching elements
        var GotElements = formattedAreaPairReport.Elements("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace()).Where(n=>n.Attribute("Level").Value == "3" && n.Attribute("Type").Value == "Group");
        if (GotElements == null)
        {
            InsertErrorMessage("There are no matching elements under <formattedAreaPairReport>.", "DeserialzieRozuctovanieMzdy");
            return;
        }

        foreach (XElement xElement in GotElements)
        {
            RozuctovanieMzda_Values(xElement, ref _pasky);
        }
    }

}

private static void addItemsToVyplatnePasky2(IEnumerable<XElement> formattedAreaPairReport, List<VyplatnePasky> _pasky)
{
    foreach (XElement xElement in formattedAreaPairReport.Elements("FormattedAreaPair".AddNamespace()))
    {
        VyplatnePasky _paska = new VyplatnePasky();
        VyplatnePasky_Items(xElement, ref _paska);

        _pasky.Add(_paska);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<XElement> tryToGetItemsFromDocument(string sPath, Func<XDocument, IEnumerable<XElement>> query, string name)
{
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(sPath);
    var report = query(document);
    if (report.Count() == 0)
    {
        //empty;
        InsertErrorMessage("<formattedAreaPairReport> contains no data! No Data to parse from.", name);
    }
    return report;
}
```

Essentially, you can keep breaking down the code and then look for duplicate idioms to clean up.  Generics may or may not come into play as part of that cleanup.  Also, you may want to give the methods better names than I have, since I'm not familiar with the native tongue being used in this code.  :-)

Comment: This looks fantastic, will definitely try this